# SQLite SELECT MAX() query returns null to cursor?

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, cursor

I have a SQLite Table called "TBL_EVO" where I want to get the biggest value from column "DATE_MODIFIED". With following query I got the result in SQLite Browser like below.

SELECT MAX(DATE_MODIFIED) FROM 'TBL_EVO';

[image]
[image]

When I run the query from code from my application I got a nullpointerexception. Database is absolutly the same like in the SQLBrowser.
So DATE_MODIFIED exists with its values.
It crashes at `cursor.moveToFirst();`.
Even when I surround it with `if(cursor.moveToFirst())`
When I do this the code jumps to else.
What am I doing wrong?

**MainActivity.java**

```
MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
String strDateTime = db.strSelectMaxDate(TableNames[intTableIDStart]);
Log.v("TBL_EVO_DATE_TIME: ", "-> "+strDateTime);
```

**MySQLiteHelper.java - strSelectMaxDate**

```
public String strSelectMaxDate(String strTable){
    String strValueFromDB = "";
    String queryMaxDate = "SELECT MAX(DATE_MODIFIED) FROM '" + strTable+"'";
    Log.v("TBL_EVO_DATE_TIME_QUERY", queryMaxDate);
    try{
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery(queryMaxDate, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor == null){
            strValueFromDB = "cursorisnull";
            Log.v("TBL_EVO_DATE_TIME_VAL1", strValueFromDB);
        }else {
            strValueFromDB = cursor.getString(0);
            Log.v("TBL_EVO_DATE_TIME_VAL2", cursor.getString(0));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v("TBL_EVO_DATE_TIME_ERROR", "-> "+e);
        strValueFromDB = "error: "+e;
    }finally{
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
    return strValueFromDB;
}
```

**Logcat**

```
09-24 15:24:23.207 21900-21917/com.spicysoftware.goexpert V/TBL_EVO_DATE_TIME_QUERY: SELECT MAX(DATE_MODIFIED) FROM 'TBL_EVO'
09-24 15:24:23.216 21900-21917/com.spicysoftware.goexpert V/TBL_EVO_DATE_TIME_ERROR: -> java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
09-24 15:24:23.216 21900-21917/com.spicysoftware.goexpert V/TBL_EVO_DATE_TIME:: -> error: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

Comment: i think cursor.getString(0) return null , am i right?

Comment: could you please add the version of android phone tested on?

Comment: `println needs a message` is definitely an interesting error, suggests that something's going wrong with the internals. When you `catch` your exceptions, can you also call `e.printStackTrace()` to show exactly where the exception is thrown?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` You're enclosing the table name in ***string delimiters***, here: `... FROM 'TBL_EVO'`.

Comment: @AnisBENNSIR It has been testet on an Android 7.0 Emulator.

Comment: @MSeiz5, could you please add Table creation statement, and confirm that all raw have DATE_MODIFIED  not null! in fact, i think that the max will always return a raw, it will be null if the group contains a null value...
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `queryMaxDate` with:

```
String queryMaxDate = "SELECT MAX(DATE_MODIFIED) FROM " + strTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I got still the same error.

Comment: pls do e.printStackTrace(); inside your catch statement then post the log.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem.
Problem was, that I did a new SQLConnection in an asynctask.

I had to open a new connection in Asynctask.